# jQuery increment value of <span> tag

Tags: jquery

I have a number in a span tag.  I need to get the value of the number in the span and then increment it inside jQuery.  I know how to do this for a text input - can this be done to a span tag?

SPAN tag

```
<span class="changeNumber"> 33 </span>
```

jQuery span selector

```
var commentNumAppend = $(this).closest(".songContainer").find(".changeNumber");
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Example -

```
<span class="changeNumber">33</span>

$('.changeNumber').html(parseInt($('.changeNumber').html(), 10)+1)
```

Comment: It is the best approach AFAIK. But feels like writing `variable:=variable+1` 30 years ago, instead of `variable++`

Comment: Is there a better way to do this where you don't have to do the selector twice?  (With a one liner)

Comment: +1 this answer...
in adition. If you want increment 1-n elements you should use each()....

   $('.customcounter').each( function() {
    $(this).html(parseInt($(this).html(), 10)+1);
   });

Answer (score 20):

You can do something like:

```
var value = parseInt($(".changeNumber").text(), 10) + 1;
$(".changeNumber").text(value);
```

JsFiddle Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/stapiagutierrez/WXAvS/1/

References:

1. [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
2. [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 7):

This is the most complete answer.

1. This solution [avoids selector repetition](http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/)
2. Handles the increment gracefully if the span does not have a value yet.

```
<span class="changeNumber"></span>
```

```
var $number = $('.changeNumber');
$number.html((parseInt($number.html(),10) || 0) + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var $span = $('#mySpanId');
$span.text(Number($span.text()) + 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Cf834/

Answer (score 1):

```
var spanVal=$("span").html();
if(!isNaN(spanVal)){

alert("value incremented"+ (++spanVal));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c84F4/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean something like this?

```
<span id="Nbr">123</span>
```

If so, the InnerHTML property will give you the content of the span

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".changeNumber").html(parseInt($(".changeNumber").html())+1)
```