# Decrement scalar Perl variable everytime an ajax script is ran

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl

On my page there is a header with a notification button that shows the number of unarchived notifications given by this Perl code:

```
@notices_posts = System::Notice->fetch_all_posts(userid => $user->userid(), visible => 1);
@regular_posts = sort { $a->created() cmp $b->created() } grep { !$_->important() } @notices_posts;
```

and displayed with this in the header:

```
<b><%= (scalar @regular_posts) %></b>
```

I have an ajax script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.archive-button', function(){
    var notice_id = $(this).data('notice_id');
    var archiveaddress = '/user/notices/archivenotice/' + notice_id;
    var archived_notice = 'tr.notification-' + notice_id;

    $.post(archiveaddress, {notice_id: notice_id}).done(function(){
        $(archived_notice).css("background" , "#F2F2F2");
    });
});
```

which runs everytime someone clicks the "archive" button on a notice. I currently have it so that the notice becomes grayed out when the perl script for archiving is successfully run but I also want it to update the scalar number in the header displaying the number of unarchived notices everytime the user archives something. Something that will decrement the displayed value possibly everytime the ajax script is ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd give the element an ID and use JQuery to set the number.

```
<b id="incme"><%= (scalar @regular_posts) %></b>
...
$(document).on('click', '.archive-button', function(){
    var notice_id = $(this).data('notice_id');
    var archiveaddress = '/user/notices/archivenotice/' + notice_id;
    var archived_notice = 'tr.notification-' + notice_id;

    $.post(archiveaddress, {notice_id: notice_id}).done(function(){
        $(archived_notice).css("background" , "#F2F2F2");
        $('#incme').html(parseInt($('#incme').html(), 10)+1)
    });
});
```

Reference:
[jQuery increment value of <span> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698729/jquery-increment-value-of-span-tag)

Comment: thanks for the reply, your script works but can you clarify whats going on in the jQuery cause i'm not familiar with that line of code. Like whats the "10" before the + 1 for?

Comment: Also, is there a way I can limit the increment to only having it function once? Because I can spam it and increment it non stop

Comment: $('#incme') is the selector. .html() is the method to get the HTML content. parseInt() is a JavaScript function that parses a string and turns it into an Integer. The '10' just says "this is decimal" versus another base (e.g., 8 for octal).

I was assuming your HTTP POST was returning when it was archived. If you have a checker CGI or something, you could poll it for status and have the incrementer happen when that successfully returns.

E.g., a nested $.post().done() that posts to the checker and doesn't return until the archive finishes.