# In html on click button values is increase or decrease by 1

Tags: html

I want to add or subtract value from given div or p tag using add or subtract button 
given code look like this

when i click on + button it increment by 1 and when i click on - it detriment by 1 value of 0 is increase or decrease.
Please help..
Thank in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrfD4.png)

Comment: I would say: go for it?

Comment: Please provide a starting point (CodePen or JSFiddle) for your question, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [jQuery increment value of <span> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698729/jquery-increment-value-of-span-tag)

You can do this:

```
<button id="plus">+</button> 
<span id="number">0</span> 
<button id="minus">-</button>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>

$("#plus").on('click', function() {
   $("#number").html(parseInt($('#number').html(), 10)+1);
});
$("#minus").on('click', function() {
   $("#number").html(parseInt($('#number').html(), 10)-1)
});

</script>
```

Comment: What is not working? Did you include the jquery library? <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
<button onclick="clicked(-1)">Previous</button>
<span id="test">--</span>
<button onclick="clicked(1)">next</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
function clicked(n) {
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    i = i + n;
    test.innerHTML = i;
};
</script>
```